# chart.TimeSeries can't add labels or change line type

Tags: r, plot, performanceanalytics

I am having some trouble with visualizing cumulative returns in R. For some reason I can't change the axis labels and line type in chart.TimeSeries or chart.CumReturns from the PerformanceAnalytics package. Changes in the line type do appear in the legend.

My code:

```
ret_compare <- cbind(conventional.scaled.returns.monthly, conditional.scaled.returns.monthly, unscaled.returns.monthly)
cum_ret_compare <- cumprod(ret_compare+1)
chart.TimeSeries(cum_ret_compare, ylab = "Cumulatief rendement", colorset= c(2,3,1),lty = 2, legend.loc = "topleft")
```

The plot I get:
[image]

A screenshot of the data I used (below is the full dput() output):

[image]

The data I used (dput(ret_compare)):

```
structure(c(0.0565939990771869, -0.0347482427707391, -0.0277900457059636, 
0.0429234080870222, -0.0718787783241953, -0.016863029966348, 
0.059355733239068, 0.037562234119064, -0.0677988560026864, 0.0600705787852096, 
-0.0517080807079698, 0.00180517117961099, -0.0209223756892264, 
0.0272845085630986, 0.0837601002893609, 0.0359655556488165, 0.0289223567394459, 
0.00786503568014307, 0.0613306520140755, -0.0691778150018606, 
0.0326380403566631, -0.0133417659847783, 0.0124121161628492, 
0.0642708816666793, 0.00507849967404161, 0.0261052878209909, 
0.0151493267776062, 0.00676515233437147, 0.00653446817356351, 
0.0150714363479285, -0.050143190382553, 0.0345058557122753, 0.0441645265494663, 
0.0330199447063566, 0.080567937081057, 0.0316571988327838, 0.000198181362019767, 
0.0208690458801075, 0.0504761702266239, -0.00550425517164699, 
0.0399051303505815, 0.0599723999392408, 0.0568078556781997, -0.047301231431996, 
0.0883885279858534, -0.0511316915459871, 0.00804493275737861, 
0.0299441033050929, 0.0334788931639478, 0.0582014365192993, 0.0678197532602445, 
0.0159992998095304, 0.0125443303556689, 0.00819301763612046, 
0.00991755318616083, -0.120605712811205, -0.0262409920857444, 
0.040946793757588, 0.0164392980283827, 0.0306621368418329, -0.0238640140220965, 
-0.0156901113780832, 0.0101061236361657, 0.0280945470081029, 
-0.0493498768067187, 0.0158476544516308, -0.0130536804845046, 
0.00928507222402164, -0.0174652889946849, 0.0415549564151227, 
0.00501328628644071, 0.141989003051248, -0.0684962605913843, 
0.0476352610219926, 0.0161558138743416, -0.0288967250807524, 
-0.0136524963030579, 0.013609536698864, -0.0101217287483828, 
-0.0158427614092369, -0.0659110431281645, -0.00361214051470649, 
-0.0339148683510243, 0.0549197973662541, 0.00351817414237154, 
-0.0836247487330098, -0.0660975163205073, 0.0304100958405675, 
-0.0433097428906102, -0.0363928303567407, 0.0106002084863943, 
-0.027020033384645, -0.0291214507902441, 0.013711263904689, 0.0191434464401923, 
0.0249660315555751, -0.0360122263475078, 0.00687569978857283, 
0.0574596331980592, -0.0114262145986058, -0.00694415263166959, 
-0.0519113175679171, -0.092809259472171, -0.000240961580031951, 
-0.0573097859137003, 0.0476330153045359, 0.0158596707003653, 
-0.0261396384934428, -0.0286505239756832, -0.0366692368775817, 
-0.0127341035075788, 0.0669385878663209, 0.0465027267386504, 
0.00704423441903423, 0.0217546431041822, -0.00582565417712289, 
0.0130023382378637, 0.10511251526633, 0.0518522334205838, 0.107127520905078, 
0.0178719315683786, 0.0278267973953032, -0.0485503100189258, 
-0.0108659147438031, 0.0109666518413147, 0.0154645672337712, 
-0.0338505700478167, -0.00436219527802972, 0.05104724595336, 
0.0541549024268144, 0.0873384487014046, 0.0628186392725139, -0.0288161017299512, 
0.0950492127308722, -0.0491296716777756, -0.0444532289596897, 
-0.00216600237045717, 0.0190268040149375, 0.067817072016372, 
0.0146918057312835, 0.0295514071747491, -0.0435830986730233, 
0.0215714644357461, 0.0494583026657589, 0.0913329109870025, -0.0053448319045083, 
0.0601557176652443, 0.0568172510761795, -0.0485426969753849, 
0.00175302828494006, 0.00984938190559648, 0.0240502738702311, 
-0.00118579262163876, 0.0561485994364315, 0.0685148593157117, 
0.04683955790033, -0.0574638736286489, -0.0138207306792366, 0.0355299071029838, 
0.0531266681464893, 0.0117742011764304, -0.00525222583312346, 
-0.0293812846037232, -0.0131594446545449, 0.0289964530305211, 
0.0360588122490606, -0.0445991604911897, -0.0133107604099818, 
-0.038145829508777, -0.000486060215306838, 0.00104676175588558, 
0.0208886233797061, -0.00263583111403876, -0.12338493810393, 
-0.0166803342153315, -0.0297568741980336, -0.112338323364713, 
-0.0693713119660443, -0.0180597800314281, 0.0134278508097088, 
-0.0330598180720567, -0.0366483220489359, 0.0339417580345724, 
0.0509050678267557, 0.0528878066096272, -0.018266616997294, 0.0677991301131817, 
0.0413170767588944, 0.0179821345844948, -0.0120530476718976, 
0.0506564243990657, 0.0108111883471529, -0.0607609892616301, 
-0.0245384465619248, 0.0513624569791613, -0.0375362970369394, 
-0.108672749280212, -0.00337217907778453, 0.087093380777213, 
-0.0338856992001196, 0.0840213297383585, 0.0404836319184165, 
-0.0844650405081253, 0.0619874075245053, 0.0504278836336267, 
0.0415781344576631, -0.0167132483670377, 0.076801882730787, -0.0369574751565279, 
-0.0206697388445634, -0.0328788588005816, -0.083383558090487, 
-0.0323162584368404, 0.051610493839749, -0.0220809995437766, 
-0.00870937103673219, 0.0225163266689465, 0.0397241319702022, 
-0.0102895797305198, -0.0281284547507554, -0.0991696936611708, 
0.0636541757418483, 0.0179711424415336, 0.0333173103972026, 0.0225887202551132, 
0.00443860666159801, 0.014806760557537, 0.0310237163003237, 0.144376590041557, 
-0.0448055417930532, -0.00513324649717639, 0.0537257308063575, 
-0.00999221359281199, -0.0819189957530423, 0.0476018428802933, 
-0.0214364641397353, 0.0918599937028983, 0.068148748800128, 0.00803440955796253, 
0.0397444044913302, -0.0552739603600437, 0.10420213043066, -0.0215270370205893, 
0.0249963705701839, -0.0093007099097957, -0.00944183950206712, 
-0.0971704450184838, 0.00264470427302532, -0.0723146624220592, 
-0.0604005470589978, 0.0267660599545763, -0.0809302399859423, 
-0.0155073183470853, 0.0664580522537737, -0.0536551996227884, 
0.0468841220908309, -0.0208428453992652, -0.0416561940283499, 
0.0333869121623922, -0.0710574857344434, -0.0493355477841083, 
0.0574454161378841, -0.0413939958360005, -0.0361717353766919, 
-0.0730611841593626, -0.0306524518642073, 0.0448704347638376, 
0.0189138798885842, -0.019112690070504, -0.0607784992411501, 
0.0200647095833417, 4.64025545323654e-05, 0.0167228957527705, 
-0.0399352463740604, -0.0533583100515406, 0.0922371375755624, 
0.0469543874397995, 0.0130431580117298, 0.0904898600303281, 0.0657425429880596, 
0.0499463961351239, -0.0261922592092307, 0.065751610214466, -0.00621555863424983, 
0.0832799329468406, 0.00866941466260029, -0.017688747365096, 
0.0449778523037858, 0.0954877576723518, -0.118831287262529, -0.0142308642932637, 
0.0385103238081386, -0.064183870293033, -0.0142310862314927, 
0.046099549894892, -0.0550393421312394, 0.00274530215199009, 
-0.156434752199699, -0.00708826723870748, -0.0462880814806087, 
0.059565753901339, 0.0316103424635057, 0.00219296046281703, 0.0485668880949881, 
-0.16121577788262, 0.0851533099681305, -0.0386176257065057, -0.0712227636357597, 
0.0312116344677249, 0.0527030336009604, 0.016990538618856, 0.0943310408154399, 
-0.0417768266816103, -0.167029346552333, -0.136573394710224, 
0.0151856742327374, 0.0150795243191497, 0.0256024944818467, 0.0319573321526792, 
0.0423101107019896, -0.060681262543504, -0.0516425733035891, 
0.160387164752116, 0.0380848238199503, -0.0206859096083852, 0.0113327971407688, 
0.0582468900635822, 0.0619978730333017, 0.077263516690542, -0.0171388878765958, 
0.0199810159760507, 0.0158023347139837, -0.103334180665634, 0.0549659271604657, 
-0.0893066705987667, 0.101606771360827, 0.0492865186589087, -0.0238877039788714, 
-0.0277900457059636, 0.0404617408226444, -0.0718787783241953, 
-0.0123575474841724, 0.059355733239068, 0.029908291943469, -0.0677988560026864, 
0.0600705787852096, -0.0437493069001588, 0.00180517117961099, 
-0.0209223756892264, 0.0272845085630986, 0.0837601002893609, 
0.0299074232605328, 0.0240446051441223, 0.00748096094707074, 
0.0613306520140755, -0.0691778150018606, 0.0246049232880761, 
-0.0133417659847783, 0.0124121161628492, 0.0642708816666793, 
0.00507849967404161, 0.0261052878209909, 0.0151493267776062, 
0.00676515233437147, 0.00653446817356351, 0.0150714363479285, 
-0.050143190382553, 0.0277659888972834, 0.0441645265494663, 0.0330199447063566, 
0.080567937081057, 0.0316571988327838, 0.00111260813987357, 0.016406229113636, 
0.0504761702266239, -0.00550425517164699, 0.0395917385160307, 
0.048456257520995, 0.0430035722547741, -0.047301231431996, 0.087565977773425, 
-0.050604038742966, 0.00804493275737861, 0.0299441033050929, 
0.0357934879374062, 0.0582014365192993, 0.0698786365111124, 0.0171741022871303, 
0.0125443303556689, 0.00819301763612046, 0.00991755318616083, 
-0.127008834727823, -0.0262409920857444, 0.040946793757588, 0.0164392980283827, 
0.0306621368418329, -0.0238640140220965, -0.0156901113780832, 
0.00959306152476125, 0.030309665786747, -0.0520373515064326, 
0.0155414686264252, -0.00868280688491285, 0.00882165631942744, 
-0.0152414835528486, 0.0354479986139713, 0.00495367631225263, 
0.0958858811432524, -0.0684962605913843, 0.0476352610219926, 
0.0161558138743416, -0.0288967250807524, -0.0136524963030579, 
0.013609536698864, -0.0101217287483828, -0.0129056749640298, 
-0.0561043848567603, -0.00361214051470649, -0.0339148683510243, 
0.0549197973662541, 0.00352545246358327, -0.0908929634017446, 
-0.0766867551408712, 0.0304100958405675, -0.0433097428906102, 
-0.0395849516878581, 0.00961086344015882, -0.0281887998980271, 
-0.0277864019559111, 0.013711263904689, 0.0191434464401923, 0.0254260098579855, 
-0.0360122263475078, 0.00713376835505675, 0.0515609918115263, 
-0.0104156632309022, -0.00554941806867115, -0.0366770391324845, 
-0.092809259472171, -0.000240961580031951, -0.0573097859137003, 
0.0476330153045359, 0.0158596707003653, -0.0261396384934428, 
-0.0286505239756832, -0.0366692368775817, -0.0127341035075788, 
0.0669385878663209, 0.0465027267386504, 0.00697103541730559, 
0.0240759738135028, -0.00499995833368028, 0.0130023382378637, 
0.0660819187835711, 0.0381905638254254, 0.081864083562877, 0.0178719315683786, 
0.0253466261092197, -0.0349542847267367, -0.0123113683808378, 
0.00922796120595493, 0.0154645672337712, -0.0256621847300804, 
-0.00257097347471802, 0.0339067339228674, 0.0356102024265696, 
0.0571472869544005, 0.0628186392725139, -0.0221911881645702, 
0.0950492127308722, -0.0491296716777756, -0.0304308647089176, 
-0.00105025749743581, 0.0190268040149375, 0.067817072016372, 
0.0118702126988408, 0.02056060572427, -0.0320256986349159, 0.0173034620187353, 
0.0348383376789623, 0.0913329109870025, -0.00508049371248243, 
0.0601557176652443, 0.0474269701349554, -0.0362187348642155, 
0.00175302828494006, 0.00984938190559648, 0.0240502738702311, 
-0.000928072811158587, 0.0422905855543541, 0.0685148593157117, 
0.031757030973413, -0.0574638736286489, -0.00959417435537924, 
0.0325380097149295, 0.0597952080195425, 0.00944188854178352, 
-0.00229856160324715, -0.0271236735291358, -0.0137710545829336, 
0.0289964530305211, 0.0360588122490606, -0.0427573578511865, 
-0.0133107604099818, -0.0413350154935502, -0.000486060215306838, 
0.00104676175588558, 0.0208886233797061, -0.00267336295134479, 
-0.0885860511912184, -0.0161029691326237, -0.0297568741980336, 
-0.112338323364713, -0.0693713119660443, -0.0180597800314281, 
0.0134278508097088, -0.0330598180720567, -0.0366483220489359, 
0.0339417580345724, 0.0509050678267557, 0.0528878066096272, -0.018266616997294, 
0.0677991301131817, 0.0413170767588944, 0.0179821345844948, -0.0121888968895034, 
0.0506564243990657, 0.0108111883471529, -0.0607609892616301, 
-0.0247113973468298, 0.0513624569791613, -0.0309923310770995, 
-0.108672749280212, -0.00337217907778453, 0.087093380777213, 
-0.0338856992001196, 0.0840213297383585, 0.0424971554686477, 
-0.081464070989248, 0.0619874075245053, 0.0430698737989899, 0.0421349243533173, 
-0.0109533653241958, 0.0742378263228765, -0.0369574751565279, 
-0.0212240452296111, -0.0328788588005816, -0.083383558090487, 
-0.0323162584368404, 0.051610493839749, -0.0220809995437766, 
-0.00870937103673219, 0.0225163266689465, 0.0438734449744449, 
-0.00892210665440751, -0.0293707722982393, -0.0991696936611708, 
0.0636541757418483, 0.0181589135552847, 0.0333173103972026, 0.0210622227911781, 
0.00487335405251677, 0.0131356170394468, 0.0273537483318715, 
0.144376590041557, -0.02796259796409, -0.00522582776545444, 0.0364354414456791, 
-0.00837134854176702, -0.0502137264472271, 0.0476018428802933, 
-0.0153208746756319, 0.0513742248497895, 0.0421405589892034, 
0.00465956984288418, 0.0215903415755918, -0.0388077343572576, 
0.0657724728057736, -0.0132884344984379, 0.0201092644054153, 
-0.0051175163129672, -0.00944183950206712, -0.0971704450184838, 
0.0016192925508538, -0.0723146624220592, -0.0604005470589978, 
0.0258782226065151, -0.0433891880670063, -0.0141086652162496, 
0.0625300971761347, -0.0301628728287874, 0.0385126964933498, 
-0.0112984784610625, -0.0323098915386699, 0.0365004974846537, 
-0.0737970611899815, -0.0493355477841083, 0.0574454161378841, 
-0.0306092896219177, -0.0262257339374732, -0.0569910029244357, 
-0.0306524518642073, 0.0448704347638376, 0.0185695069363463, 
-0.0155548984204991, -0.0467627599243856, 0.0200647095833417, 
8.29964155073526e-05, 0.0167228957527705, -0.0335972446871899, 
-0.0294344648848727, 0.0518143754361482, 0.0257859588754956, 
0.00824571243269778, 0.0904898600303281, 0.0657425429880596, 
0.0415235900563797, -0.0261922592092307, 0.065751610214466, -0.00621555863424983, 
0.0832799329468406, 0.00866941466260029, -0.017688747365096, 
0.0449778523037858, 0.0954877576723518, -0.118831287262529, -0.0153069547305189, 
0.0218515179870005, -0.0342686779423506, -0.00850677257427712, 
0.0325477383763988, -0.0306141018335595, 0.00243501209588759, 
-0.156434752199699, -0.005029743685798, -0.0345290845779366, 
0.059565753901339, 0.0252512069665196, 0.00207064965943626, 0.0302923006737879, 
-0.16121577788262, 0.0654457174010914, -0.0209269433762712, -0.0712227636357597, 
0.0269825779272959, 0.0307477365084228, 0.0141733437604381, 0.0943310408154399, 
-0.023119978605681, -0.0967380201240571, -0.147305013179531, 
0.0151856742327374, 0.0150795243191497, 0.0256024944818467, 0.0319573321526792, 
0.0389645831394516, -0.0516711678172406, -0.057263622404775, 
0.17035185335458, 0.0380848238199503, -0.014964951245554, 0.00815821494412972, 
0.0582468900635822, 0.0410152743642858, 0.077263516690542, -0.014889383359691, 
0.0128841652906317, 0.0126255977120013, -0.103334180665634, 0.0438272536940851, 
-0.0576089770159162, 0.0647885069687177, 0.0492865186589087, 
-0.0238877039788714, -0.0300054599177805, 0.0404617408226444, 
-0.0429596698815269, -0.0123575474841724, 0.0417189496432033, 
0.029908291943469, -0.0409145877912638, 0.0416155635440896, -0.0437493069001588, 
0.00282867922883168, -0.00940990309615575, 0.0190579142175993, 
0.0443042237259872, 0.0299074232605328, 0.0240446051441223, 0.00748096094707074, 
0.0443570938433033, -0.0404571419085026, 0.0246049232880761, 
-0.0066025249154531, 0.00954964988443341, 0.0298053972087278, 
0.00476107372301793, 0.0175757232170388, 0.0101068360663179, 
0.00609368513738762, 0.00540196687039063, 0.00917053509817412, 
-0.0216215093591073, 0.0277659888972834, 0.0226023268044275, 
0.0213902871313327, 0.0443373040422519, 0.0176332357221722, 0.00111260813987357, 
0.016406229113636, 0.0298863069339816, -0.006561222645037, 0.0395917385160307, 
0.048456257520995, 0.0430035722547741, -0.0585570779808038, 0.087565977773425, 
-0.050604038742966, 0.0108699498782903, 0.0350978073788761, 0.0357934879374062, 
0.0665716262589837, 0.0698786365111124, 0.0171741022871303, 0.0148956336813075, 
0.00971692648248834, 0.0118976448527714, -0.127008834727823, 
-0.0643807858901128, 0.0785395421983646, 0.0341359119905573, 
0.0424124006976598, -0.0297507849081639, -0.0284978431148246, 
0.00959306152476125, 0.030309665786747, -0.0520373515064326, 
0.0155414686264252, -0.00868280688491285, 0.00882165631942744, 
-0.0152414835528486, 0.0354479986139713, 0.00495367631225263, 
0.0958858811432524, -0.0754119883858065, 0.0605889700089284, 
0.0230055503982476, -0.0452346298784714, -0.0199167187040488, 
0.0202669563997153, -0.0151015261797287, -0.0129056749640298, 
-0.0561043848567603, -0.00874332327370753, -0.0450463176390838, 
0.0676450859834781, 0.00352545246358327, -0.0908929634017446, 
-0.0766867551408712, 0.0683714108587556, -0.0562536535683003, 
-0.0395849516878581, 0.00961086344015882, -0.0281887998980271, 
-0.0277864019559111, 0.0315316866110831, 0.0278566332045715, 
0.0254260098579855, -0.0478119064346871, 0.00713376835505675, 
0.0515609918115263, -0.0104156632309022, -0.00554941806867115, 
-0.0366770391324845, -0.128540218463314, -0.00333101415653492, 
-0.120107648833262, 0.0958295457008402, 0.0354990847462275, -0.0370024578753033, 
-0.035961013075631, -0.0473812313231093, -0.0190728925526511, 
0.129179809515038, 0.0580707168491923, 0.00697103541730559, 0.0240759738135028, 
-0.00499995833368028, 0.00801345581575896, 0.0660819187835711, 
0.0381905638254254, 0.081864083562877, 0.0102074178146554, 0.0253466261092197, 
-0.0349542847267367, -0.0123113683808378, 0.00922796120595493, 
0.0190388963276953, -0.0256621847300804, -0.00257097347471802, 
0.0339067339228674, 0.0356102024265696, 0.0571472869544005, 0.037933876312189, 
-0.0221911881645702, 0.04867790190674, -0.0284893707600057, -0.0304308647089176, 
-0.00105025749743581, 0.0113296046090396, 0.0384517691761184, 
0.0118702126988408, 0.02056060572427, -0.0320256986349159, 0.0173034620187353, 
0.0348383376789623, 0.055078009042417, -0.00508049371248243, 
0.0349324182903621, 0.0474269701349554, -0.0362187348642155, 
0.000731944005366358, 0.0126588629475626, 0.0284200411474285, 
-0.000928072811158587, 0.0422905855543541, 0.0344914231782354, 
0.031757030973413, -0.0204446138767127, -0.00959417435537924, 
0.0325380097149295, 0.0597952080195425, 0.00944188854178352, 
-0.00229856160324715, -0.0271236735291358, -0.0137710545829336, 
0.048844176339206, 0.0455008063339308, -0.0427573578511865, -0.0178282872713298, 
-0.0413350154935502, -0.00251312075281451, 0.000392568409978589, 
0.038867708087317, -0.00267336295134479, -0.0885860511912184, 
-0.0161029691326237, -0.0420241198590325, -0.140933679398404, 
-0.213182576299088, -0.092462713370572, 0.0518406558167939, -0.0897576490474823, 
-0.0843476608722317, 0.0665382076070802, 0.131582448235168, 0.107795304196951, 
-0.0220904436860068, 0.105306956007685, 0.0603934116278224, 0.0236136189048726, 
-0.0121888968895034, 0.0658652385210567, 0.0143138180286164, 
-0.0670856183281777, -0.0247113973468298, 0.0618092509209986, 
-0.0309923310770995, -0.128803242463851, -0.00934578652654638, 
0.12464789947184, -0.0389238136806155, 0.105292759441438, 0.0424971554686477, 
-0.081464070989248, 0.0801304884170133, 0.0430698737989899, 0.0421349243533173, 
-0.0109533653241958, 0.0742378263228765, -0.0412233371318413, 
-0.0212240452296111, -0.038721073177811, -0.102593285857173, 
-0.0660128643244059, 0.120312560041835, -0.0445404035530143, 
-0.0160245207220792, 0.0264519215884826, 0.0438734449744449, 
-0.00892210665440751, -0.0293707722982393, -0.131667864804966, 
0.0765524648247053, 0.0181589135552847, 0.0410867753199928, 0.0210622227911781, 
0.00487335405251677, 0.0131356170394468, 0.0273537483318715, 
0.0525736688028997, -0.02796259796409, -0.00522582776545444, 
0.0364354414456791, -0.00837134854176702, -0.0502137264472271, 
0.0532240511918611, -0.0153208746756319, 0.0513742248497895, 
0.0421405589892034, 0.00465956984288418, 0.0215903415755918, 
-0.0388077343572576, 0.0657724728057736, -0.0132884344984379, 
0.0201092644054153, -0.0051175163129672, -0.00294532574721995, 
-0.0342077361930025, 0.0016192925508538, -0.0379594485162568, 
-0.0270255520457952, 0.0258782226065151, -0.0433891880670063, 
-0.0141086652162496, 0.0625300971761347, -0.0301628728287874, 
0.0385126964933498, -0.0112984784610625, -0.0323098915386699, 
0.0365004974846537, -0.0737970611899815, -0.0556600639245958, 
0.0705786039020948, -0.0306092896219177, -0.0262257339374732, 
-0.0569910029244357, -0.0405411931490601, 0.0592431057525111, 
0.0185695069363463, -0.0155548984204991, -0.0467627599243856, 
0.0477649909637343, 8.29964155073526e-05, 0.00912820625534794, 
-0.0335972446871899, -0.0294344648848727, 0.0518143754361482, 
0.0257859588754956, 0.00824571243269778, 0.0364118589045417, 
0.0311793838385637, 0.0415235900563797, -0.0130142562807395, 
0.0340778557667032, -0.00227377328383616, 0.0347900685331286, 
0.00384546460879642, -0.00418305832682986, 0.0144009024701055, 
0.0443595078891013, -0.0509816485786232, -0.0153069547305189, 
0.0218515179870005, -0.0342686779423506, -0.00850677257427712, 
0.0325477383763988, -0.0306141018335595, 0.00243501209588759, 
-0.0772496207460813, -0.005029743685798, -0.0345290845779366, 
0.0670034415430896, 0.0252512069665196, 0.00207064965943626, 
0.0302923006737879, -0.0635789495123614, 0.0654457174010914, 
-0.0209269433762712, -0.0282304959937522, 0.0269825779272959, 
0.0307477365084228, 0.0141733437604381, 0.0384548002293232, -0.023119978605681, 
-0.0967380201240571, -0.147305013179531, 0.0566080914066258, 
0.0267254767970793, 0.0387793305132154, 0.0441493507889792, 0.0389645831394516, 
-0.0516711678172406, -0.057263622404775, 0.17035185335458, 0.0462477698800481, 
-0.014964951245554, 0.00815821494412972, 0.0272545550529284, 
0.0410152743642858, 0.0388027775914868, -0.014889383359691, 0.0128841652906317, 
0.0126255977120013, -0.0535302063156535, 0.0438272536940851, 
-0.0576089770159162, 0.0647885069687177), .Dim = c(336L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Conventionele.strategie", "Conditionele.strategie", 
    "Niet.geschaald")), index = structure(c(759974400, 762393600, 
765072000, 767577600, 770342400, 772934400, 775440000, 778291200, 
780883200, 783561600, 786153600, 788745600, 791510400, 793929600, 
796608000, 799027200, 801878400, 804470400, 807148800, 809827200, 
812332800, 815097600, 817689600, 820195200, 823046400, 825552000, 
828057600, 830822400, 833500800, 835920000, 838771200, 841363200, 
844041600, 846720000, 849225600, 851990400, 854668800, 857088000, 
859766400, 862358400, 864950400, 867628800, 870307200, 872812800, 
875577600, 878256000, 880675200, 883526400, 886118400, 888537600, 
891302400, 893894400, 896400000, 899164800, 901843200, 904521600, 
907113600, 909705600, 912384000, 915062400, 917568000, 919987200, 
922838400, 925430400, 927849600, 930700800, 933292800, 936057600, 
938649600, 941155200, 943920000, 946598400, 949276800, 951782400, 
954460800, 956880000, 959731200, 962323200, 965001600, 967680000, 
970185600, 972950400, 975542400, 978048000, 980899200, 983318400, 
985910400, 988588800, 991267200, 993772800, 996537600, 999216000, 
1001635200, 1004486400, 1007078400, 1009756800, 1012435200, 1014854400, 
1017273600, 1020124800, 1022803200, 1025222400, 1028073600, 1030665600, 
1033344000, 1036022400, 1038528000, 1041292800, 1043971200, 1046390400, 
1049068800, 1051660800, 1054252800, 1056931200, 1059609600, 1062115200, 
1064880000, 1067558400, 1069977600, 1072828800, 1075420800, 1077840000, 
1080691200, 1083283200, 1085702400, 1088553600, 1091145600, 1093910400, 
1096502400, 1099008000, 1101772800, 1104451200, 1107129600, 1109548800, 
1112227200, 1114732800, 1117497600, 1120089600, 1122595200, 1125446400, 
1128038400, 1130716800, 1133308800, 1135900800, 1138665600, 1141084800, 
1143763200, 1146182400, 1149033600, 1151625600, 1154304000, 1156982400, 
1159488000, 1162252800, 1164844800, 1167350400, 1170201600, 1172620800, 
1175212800, 1177891200, 1180569600, 1183075200, 1185840000, 1188518400, 
1190937600, 1193788800, 1196380800, 1199059200, 1201737600, 1204243200, 
1206921600, 1209513600, 1212105600, 1214784000, 1217462400, 1219968000, 
1222732800, 1225411200, 1227830400, 1230681600, 1233273600, 1235692800, 
1238457600, 1241049600, 1243555200, 1246320000, 1248998400, 1251676800, 
1254268800, 1256860800, 1259539200, 1262217600, 1264723200, 1267142400, 
1269993600, 1272585600, 1275004800, 1277856000, 1280448000, 1283212800, 
1285804800, 1288310400, 1291075200, 1293753600, 1296432000, 1298851200, 
1301529600, 1304035200, 1306800000, 1309392000, 1311897600, 1314748800, 
1317340800, 1320019200, 1322611200, 1325203200, 1327968000, 1330473600, 
1333065600, 1335744000, 1338422400, 1340928000, 1343692800, 1346371200, 
1348790400, 1351641600, 1354233600, 1356912000, 1359590400, 1362009600, 
1364428800, 1367280000, 1369958400, 1372377600, 1375228800, 1377820800, 
1380499200, 1383177600, 1385683200, 1388448000, 1391126400, 1393545600, 
1396224000, 1398816000, 1401408000, 1404086400, 1406764800, 1409270400, 
1412035200, 1414713600, 1417132800, 1419984000, 1422576000, 1424995200, 
1427760000, 1430352000, 1432857600, 1435622400, 1438300800, 1440979200, 
1443571200, 1446163200, 1448841600, 1451520000, 1454025600, 1456704000, 
1459382400, 1461888000, 1464652800, 1467244800, 1469750400, 1472601600, 
1475193600, 1477872000, 1480464000, 1483056000, 1485820800, 1488240000, 
1490918400, 1493337600, 1496188800, 1498780800, 1501459200, 1504137600, 
1506643200, 1509408000, 1.512e+09, 1514505600, 1517356800, 1519776000, 
1522281600, 1525046400, 1527724800, 1530230400, 1532995200, 1535673600, 
1538092800, 1540944000, 1543536000, 1546214400, 1548892800, 1551312000, 
1553817600, 1556582400, 1559260800, 1561680000, 1564531200, 1567123200, 
1569801600, 1572480000, 1574985600, 1577750400, 1580428800, 1582848000, 
1585612800, 1588204800, 1590710400, 1593475200, 1596153600, 1598832000, 
1601424000, 1604016000, 1606694400, 1609372800, 1611878400, 1614297600, 
1617148800, 1619740800, 1622160000, 1625011200, 1627603200, 1630368000, 
1632960000, 1635465600, 1638230400, 1640908800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(ret_compare)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: It is (336 x 3) xts file, so it is quite big. I've just included the beginning and the end to keep it short, if you need more let me know. structure(c(0.0565939990771869, -0.0347482427707391, -0.0277900457059636, ..., -0.0576089770159162, 0.0647885069687177), .Dim = c(336L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Conventionele.strategie", "Conditionele.strategie", "Niet.geschaald")), index = structure(c(759974400, 762393600, 
765072000, 767577600,..., 1640908800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))

Comment: could you please share your data in the question?

Comment: I've added it, let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Here are some alternatives:  `plot(ret_compare, lty = 2, col = 2:4)` or `library(ggplot2); autoplot(ret_compare, facets = NULL, lty = I(2))`  .

Answer (score 0):

Similar to you, I could only affect the legend by changing `lty` or `lwd` parameters. The package authors state that

> "This function is intended to be used inside other charting functions."
> — `?chart.TimeSeries`

Indeed, you can select a `plot.engine` by passing it a function argument: `plot.engine = "ggplot2"` will return and plot a `ggplot` graph, "plotly" an interactive plotly-plot and so on. Then again you'll need the corresponding libraries installed and some basic aquaintance with each package (so I wonder why to use `chart.TimeSeries` as a wrapper anyway).

**Edit** - two alternatives to plot your data with `library(ggplot2)`

1. Fast and simple:

```
cum_ret_compare %>% autoplot.zoo
```

2. with basic `dplyr` and `ggplot` operations:

```
my_plot <- 
cum_ret_compare %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(time(cum_ret_compare))) %>% ## extract date to column Date
  ## stack variables instead of side-by-side
  ## to easier apply variable-wise color further down:
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date,
               names_to = 'strategy_type',
               values_to = 'value'
               ) %>%
  ## construct ggplot
  ggplot(aes(Date, value)) +
  ## add lines per strategy_type
  geom_line(aes(col = strategy_type),
            lty = 1, ## linetype
            lwd = .1 ## linewidth
            ) +
  labs(x = 'Date', y = 'cum. return')

## plot it:
my_plot

## make it look impressive ;-)
library(ggthemes)
my_plot + theme_economist()
```

Comment: I will just use the plot() function instead of chart.TimeSeries(), that seems like the easiest and most convenient solution. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I added two suggestions to use your data with `ggplot`. Graag :-)